# Does it STILL make sense to convert primary to logical drives even on a UEFI, so not an MBR system/PC/laptop

Tags: partitioning, conversion, boot-partition, logical-drive

I have a Windows 10 laptop. I've partitioned the 1 TB drive into 4 parts and I'm in the process of making it into the the *CLASSIC* setup of:

[ OS1 | OS2 | APPS | DATA | Recovery ]

I've noticed that Windows native *"Disk Management"** makes them into primary partitions, which was a definite no-no on disks that were "formatted" under MBR, way back when: You  had to make them logical to get more partitions.

Now, it seems UEFI formatted systems does not care about all that, so my question is:

**Does it still make sense, to convert primary to logical drives, even if you are using UEFI?**

Comment: *Does it still make sense...?*  No, absolutely not! Why even ask if you already have a GPT drive where it doesn't matter? Perhaps you're trying to solve some other issue and this is an X-Y problem?

Comment: Considering GPT does not have a 4 partition limit like MBR does, it absolutely does not make sense to break the mold, and make them logical partitions.  There isn't a need to do so.  I don't believe you could even boot a Windows installation if it was within a logical partition so your idea has major flaws in it.  As already pointed out, extended and logical partitions,only exist to provide compatibility with legacy systems.  Linux has no problems with EFI support when dealing with Hybrid MBR, MBR will take precedence when dealing with Windows.

Answer (score 8):

If you are using UEFI, then your disk is in
[GPT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GUID_Partition_Table)
format.

Under GPT you can have up to 128 partitions and do not need to distinguish between "primary" and "extended" partitions.

So the answer is : No point in converting primary to logical partitions under
UEFI/GPT.

Comment: would there be a disadvantage to converting them to logical?

Comment: @GwenKillerby There are no "primary", "extended" or "logical" partitions in GPT drives, they're all the same.

Comment: @GwenKillerby - Do not break the mold.  There is absolutely no reason to use logical and extended partitions if you are using the GPT format.

Comment: A GPT disk can only contain primary partitions, or rather, there is no concept of primary or logical. Trust your operating system to do the right thing.